# Unwanted extra li element in unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

So, I have an unordered list which contains buttons for a keypad. The problem is that for some reason, There's an extra `<li>` element in the end of the list and this just ends up screwing everything. How could I fix this?

```
<ul id="buttons">
   <li><div><a><span>1</span></a></div><div><a><span>2</span></a></div><div><a><span>3</span></a></div></li>
   <li><div><a><span>4</span></a></div><div><a><span>5</span></a></div><div><a><span>6</span></a></div></li>
   <li><div><a><span>7</span></a></div><div><a><span>8</span></a></div><div><a><span>9</span></a></div></li>
   <li style="max-width:80px;margin:auto;"><div><a><span>0</span></a></div><li>
</ul>
//as you can see only 4 li elements

//styles
li {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 10px 5px;
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

[image: 5 <li> elements]

But when I open the document in chrome, There are 5 `<li>` elements.

Comment: You did not close your last li element. I recommend using the forward slash button :]

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo error. Problem is at  your last list item . It is not closed properly. It should be like this :

```
 <li style="max-width:80px;margin:auto;"><div><a><span>0</span></a></div></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `<li>` instead of `</li>` to close your last list item

so your could should be

```
<ul id="buttons">
 <li>
   <div><a><span>1</span></a></div>
   <div><a><span>2</span></a></div>
   <div><a><span>3</span></a></div>
 </li>
 <li>
   <div><a><span>4</span></a></div>
   <div><a><span>5</span></a></div>
   <div><a><span>6</span></a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div><a><span>7</span></a></div>
  <div><a><span>8</span></a></div>
  <div><a><span>9</span></a></div>
</li>
<li style="max-width:80px;margin:auto;">
 <div><a><span>0</span></a></div>
 </li>
```

Comment: This was my issue as well and this answer explains the best. Still works in 2019. I had this issue in my PHP file.